# Cannot trigger click for dynamic content generated

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, handlebars.js

I have this situation that i need to trigger click on some element from clicking other element. More concretly - i have gallery with thumbnails. When you hover over the thumbnail - the description box covers the whole thumbnail. After that i need to trigger click event on the thumbnail so it can run lightbox. To achieve this i need to do something when i click on the description.

This is the html:

```
<div id="gallery">
<!-- Content from handlebars that is loaded dynamicaly from template file via ajax -->
    <a class="lightbox lightbox-frame" href="img/gallery/{{filename}}.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery" data-category="{{category}}">
        <img src="img/gallery/thumbs/{{filename}}.jpg" alt=""/>
    </a>
    <p class="gallery-image-description">{{description}}</p>
<!-- Content from handlebars -->
</div>
```

I am trying this but it does not work. It works for statick content but this content is loaded via Ajax and then compiled with Handlebars:

```
('#gallery').on('click', '.gallery-image-description', function () {
    $(this).prev().click();
});
```

So the question is: Do you have any idea how i can trigger click event on dynamicaly generated content, by clicking on other element ?

Comment: What is being loaded there? I hope not an element with id `gallery`? Or is the whole HTML you show there being loaded dynamically? In which case your event delegation won't work.

Comment: No the <div id="gallery"></div> element is static. The content that is loaded is appended to this div.

Comment: add an onclick handler in your template onclick="openLbox(this)" or add a click handler to the parent and get the target element that was clicked.

Comment: @nzhul: did you try delegate ?
[delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will help because I've never used lightbox, and I can't be sure that there isn't an interaction between lightbox and the JS.

But here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/f2ovmfjb/1/) that

Has a dynamically generated div/image

On hover, covers the image with text

A click on the parent pops up an alert

JS

```
$('.imagestuff').on('click', function(){
       alert('clicked');
});
```